# Deploy Apple OSX images from a Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, mac-osx, mac, operating-system

We are mostly a Windows shop but more and more Macs are being used.

Is there any software that would run on Windows Server 2008 R2 that could be used to image Apple computers?

Comment: I am interested in this as well.  Acronis Snap Deploy can do linux, but doesn't go into details.  Does OSX even support what you are trying to do? (generic image install similar to say a generic windows image and then runnign sysprep)

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this a while ago. It appears that a process very similar to Linux pxeboot is possible.

Basically extract the kernel and drivers - much like vmlinuz and init.rd on Linux - and boot an os from an nfs or http location.

See http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090317042911165 for details.

On a related note the pxe and http servers can both be windows or Linux. I have tried both at one point or another.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into this and get back to you with what I find.